# JSON.Net Deseralize json pair to Object Propery

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Ok I have WebApi application that is sending back name value pairs like so

```
{'FirstName':'SomeGuy'}
```

On the server the FirstName field is not just a string, it is a generic object that hold additional information about FirstName, and is not send back from the client.

Here is a outline of the classes

```
public abstract class Field
{
 protected object _value;
  ......More Properties/Methods
  public bool HasValue
    {
        get { return _hasValue; }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return _hasValue ? _value : null; }
    }

    protected void SetValue(object value, bool clearHasValue = false)
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = clearHasValue ?
            false :
            value != null;
    }
}

public class Field<T> : Field
{
  ..Constructors and methods
  public new T Value
    {
        get { return _hasValue ? (T)_value : default(T); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }
}
```

So.. In theory I may be trying to bind to a model like

```
 class FieldModel
    {
        public Field<string> FirstName { get; set; }
        public Field<string> LastName { get; set; }
        public Field<Decimal> Amount { get; set; }

        public FieldModel()
        {
            FirstName = new Field<string>();
            LastName = new Field<string>();
            Amount = new Field<decimal>();
        }
    }
```

So here is the issue.. I want FirstName in my json object to deseralize to right property. Now if I modify the json package to `{'FirstName.Value':'SomeGuy'}` JSON.net works out of the box, but I really not to do that. I have been tying to make my own JsonConverter but have not been able to get that to work. So, I don't think this should be very hard, but I am a bit stuck.

### EDIT

So.. I did come up with a solution that works, but I have to think there is a better way.. It uses dynamics and I have to think that I am missing an easy solution.

```
public class FieldConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var internalVal = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault());
        var retVal = existingValue as dynamic;
        retVal.Value = internalVal as dynamic;
        return retVal;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Field));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use JSON.NET?  I could not more highly recommend it.  Making your JsonConverter is going to really hard...there are lots of edge cases you'll have to worry about to make it correct and complete.  JSON.NET is well tested, trusted and used by just about everyone, and distributed as a NuGet package.  What more could you want!  In fact, if you're using ASP.NET Web API, you're already using it...Web API uses JSON.NET to handle JSON parsing internally.  My recommendation: save yourself the time and just use JSON.NET

Comment: I am using JSON.Net JsonConverter is the base class to override to customize JSON.Net Serialization and Deserialization

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with JSON.NET's CustomCreationConverter.  Here's an [example](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html#):

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}

public class PersonConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Person>
{
    public override Person Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Employee();
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
string json = @"{
  'Department': 'Furniture',
  'JobTitle': 'Carpenter',
  'FirstName': 'John',
  'LastName': 'Joinery',
  'BirthDate': '1983-02-02T00:00:00'
}";

Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json, new PersonConverter());

Console.WriteLine(person.GetType().Name);
// Employee

Employee employee = (Employee)person;

Console.WriteLine(employee.JobTitle);
// Carpenter
```

Comment: Well I tried this, and I was unable to get it to work with abstract base and a generic child class.. If you can provide a more detailed example.

Comment: What didn't work about it..? you should show what you've tried

Comment: Sorry for the light detail before.. I was on my phone. Anyway.. First you can create a abstract class directly, but hat is not really the big deal. It that the generic type to be constructed is not know at. that is unless I create a Converter for each and every model I use, and that would be a bit cumbersome.